# Calculations for groups of data

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, zip

I have 3 columns of data in an excel sheet. The first column represents zip codes, the second represents values in that zip code and the third column represents the frequency of that value in the zip code.

Currently, if a zip code has multiple values, it is listed multiple times in a column with it's corresponding value and the frequency. Therefore, there are many rows of data for each zip code.

I have linked a picture of my data.

I need to calculate the standard deviation, min, max, mean etc. of all the values in every zip code,taking into account the frequency at which they appear. I have been going through all the zip codes manually and calculating everything for it one by one. Is there a faster way to do this?

[image]

Comment: I was trying to post an answer to your first question when you deleted it. :( I'll post what I had and let you sort it out.

Comment: By the way, you don’t need to delete your question and recreate it; you can [edit] it.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is not complete, but it will get you started.

Add a `SUM` column to the right of FREQUENCY. Add a formula to calculate the BI by the FREQUENCY; `=B2*C2`. Then copy this formula down the column. This will give you the numbers to work with to determine the other values you desire.

Now start a new column for each ZIP code you want data for. In my example below I used `G1` and `H1`.  Under each of these you are going to enter an array formula to calculate the values you desire.  Let’s work on 43015 first.

[image]

In `S2` enter `=AVERAGE(IF(($A:$A=G1),($D:$D)))`, then press <kbd>F2</kbd>. To make it an array press  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> together. It will put the formula in `{}` if done correctly.  This formula will look in column A to find the ZIP that matches cell `G1`, then averages the values in column D matching the ZIP.

With cell `G2` selected, drag the lower right corner to the cell for 43016 and release. This should automatically adjust for the shift and calculate according to cell `H1`.

You are going to do the same thing for the following formulas.

For Min; `=MIN(IF(($A:$A=G1),($B:$B)))`

For Max; `=MAX(IF(($A:$A=G1),($B:$B)))`

Stand Dev; `=STDEV(IF(($A:$A=G1),(($B:$B)*($B:$B)*($C:$C))))`

Note: if you change anything in the formulas after you make them an array, you will have to make them an array again by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: I wasn't able to figure out how to use the `MODE` function with this setup, but maybe you, or someone else can. As far as range, if its what I think you want, it's just `MAX`-`MIN`.

Comment: You say “In `S2` enter …” I suspect you meant “In `G2` enter …”

Comment: I don’t have `STDEV.P` in my Excel (2007).  I guess it’s from an Add-In.  Please clarify.

Comment: How can I put this tactfully? Your answers are all … other than correct. Look at the data: for Zip code 43015 there are 40 (18+18+4) data points, all between 1.00 and 1.05. But your “Min” and “Max” values are _way_ outside that range.  That’s an easy fix: make those formulae look at Column B rather than Column D. Your “Mean” value is the average of the three values 18.378, 18.558, and 4.164; it needs to be weighted by the Column C counts. StandDev is a bit harder; I believe that a good approach would be to set Column `E` to `B2*B2*C2`, so you can get a sum of the squares of the data points.

Comment: Also, in your results area (Column F and beyond), why do you put the key values (Zip code) in columns rather than rows?

Comment: @Scott You're right. I had adjusted the sheet to be in the same column names as the OP had. Then the original question was deleted, so I had to shift things to put the answer here when the question was re-posted. Guess I didn't get all the changes made properly. Thanks for pointing it out. As far as the format of columns over rows, it's just one of many ways to do it.

Comment: @Scott Regarding `STDEV.P`, the OP didn't say what version of Excel, so I used what I have available.

Comment: Regarding `STDEV.P`, my point is that, in case it isn’t available in the OP’s environment, you should tell him how to get it (if you know).

Comment: It's not an add in. It is a standard function within current versions of Excel. Older versions use `STDEV`. Since the OP did not state what version, I assume current unless they state otherwise.

Comment: Thanks to @Scott I have corrected some formula issues and updated the image to be more accurate. Also, the `STDEV` function is being used for backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Building on CharlieRB’s answer, you can get MODE in Row 6 by entering the array formula

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($A:$A=G1), --($C:$C=MAX(IF(($A:$A=G1), ($C:$C)))), ($B:$B))
```

in cell G6.

Comment: Oops. This doesn’t work if the mode is non-unique (as in CharlieRB’s example data).